# Help to choose best option that fit in paragraph

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, meaning, words

> A社がインターネット関連会社と組み、月額料金10万5千円で販売を始めたソフトは、社名や製品名などをキーワードとして設定すると、掲示板やブログの中から関連した記述を集めてきてくれる。
>
> ただ記述を並べられても、皆読むのは大変。そこで、プラスマイナスのどちらの評価が多いか分析する機能をつけた。
>
> 例えば、文中「いい」「素晴らしい」があればプラス、「悪い」「ひどい」があればマイナスというように、事前に用意された辞書に従ってシステムが判断していく。
>
> **しかし、日本語は単純ではない。例えば「―はいいが、―は気にくわない」というように、相反する評価が並ぶとソフトが「良い」「悪い」を判断できず中立にしてしまう。前後の文脈を加えた解析や、業界ごと特有の表現への対応など、精度を上げていく＿＿＿＿＿。**
>
> 1. ことは不可能である
> 2. 余地があるという
> 3. はずである
> 4. はずではない

The answer is 余地があるという. Why is it not はずである？ I know that 相反する評価が並ぶとソフトが「良い」「悪い」を判断できず中立にしてしまう this part showing unsatisfied feeling

前後の文脈を加えた解析や、業界ごと特有の表現への対応など、精度を上げていく＿＿＿＿ And the last sentence said that to sum up, in order to correspond to every special industry expression, there is room to improve accuracy (?) there is a room means they should work hard to improve accuracy?
Why not はずである？

Comment: Some more context is needed to answer this question. Is this an interview with a developer? The person who wrote this is a writer who himself is not a technologist?

Comment: No its an article about company using computer in order to automatically classifying customer reviews whether reviews good or not then publish it on site, but computer sometimes wrong in classifying reviews. I only post the last part of the paragraph ><

Answer (score 2, accepted):

～する余地がある means "there is room for ～ing" and 精度を上げていく余地がある indeed means "there is room for improving accuracy". But the use of 余地がある is not very important to determine the correct answer here.

The critical difference between 3 and 4 is ～という and ～はずだ. [Sentence-end ～という](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33563/5010) is used to repeat someone else's statement ("they say ...", "according to them, ..."), whereas ～はずだ is used to show the writer's own strong expectation ("I think they will ...", "they must ...").

Apparently, this article is written from the third person's standpoint, by someone who do not develop this system. Typically, this looks like a news article based on a press release from the manufacturer or an interview with the developer. In such a setting, in general, a writer (who is not necessarily an expert in this field) rarely gives his own technical opinion using はずだ in the middle of the article. Perhaps the writer even did not see the system before writing this.

Please re-read the question carefully, and see which fits the context better:

- 精度を上げていくはずだ ≒ "I, as an interviewer/writer, am sure that they will improve the accuracy (for some reason)" or "Everyone should naturally expect that they will improve the accuracy".
- 精度を上げていく余地があるという ≒ "According to the developers, there is still some room for improvement"

---

**EDIT:** To reach the correct answer, it is important to make a correct assumption regarding **who wrote this article**. There are a number of reasons to believe this was *not* officially written by someone on behalf of A社. In general, official announcements are far politer (です, ます, *keigo*) and use more formal wordings. For instance, compare [this official announcement](http://www.jp.playstation.com/info/release/nr-20160824-ds4-usbwa.html) and [this news article](http://ascii.jp/elem/000/001/216/1216915/). They both convey the same information, but they look drastically different. Noticed that only the latter article uses という? Actually I'm pretty confident that this writing style is that of a typical technical news writer. Thus everything in the article is basically hearsay information based on another information source.

And most importantly, there is no way that one wants to use はず in an article like this, because はず expresses the speaker's *subjective* impression/understanding. If this were written by someone on behalf of A社 or in charge of the actual development of the system, concluding the announcement saying 精度を上げていくはずだ ("It *appears* that (or in our understanding) we will improve...") would sound totally irresponsible and funny. Instead, they should clearly state 精度を上げていく予定です, 精度の向上に努めます, etc. If this is written by someone not directly related to A社 (e.g., a writer of wired.com), suddenly saying something subjective like 精度を上げていくはずだ is out of the question, too.

Comment: Ah ~to iu is the key because **前後の文脈を加えた**解析や means to emphasize the prior part right(?) but i also cant judge what is the writer position. At first i thought that -はずである is right because prior part said about unsatisfied feeling about the software and the latter part supposed to emphasize prior part right(加え)(？) ah but then i think again if i put はずである  it also doesnt fit because the prior part doesnt said anything about advancement of the software(?)

Comment: @DevinaMuljono Please take a look at the edit. Unfortunately, the *local* context of the single paragraph is not enough.

Comment: Thankyou so much!!! I think so this paragraph looks like new article based on press release and also it a bit weird to suddenly tell your own impression especially in the end conclusion of the sentence where there are no sign of the speaker telling want to improve the system, its all about unsatisfied feeling and demerit of the system(?) And i also think to use ~はず there should be a proof in front of はず (?) to emphasis subjective impression(?)

Comment: ~という in this sentence 多様な対応デバイスからストリーミング経由でプレーできるようになるという。is to report someone statement (?) I think Its similar to ということです(?)

Comment: @DevinaMuljono It is the developers of the system who are aware of the current weakness of the system, and it is the same people who are planning to improve the system. Again, the person who wrote this knows almost nothing about the system. Read as if every sentence had "according to A社" at the beginning. And yes, という becomes ということです in polite form.

Answer (score 2):

> 前後の文脈を加えた解析や、業界ごと特有の表現への対応など、精度を上げていくはずである。

(3) is a wrong answer because, this (above) is not grammatical.

The following would be:

- a. （※） 前後の文脈を加えた解析や、業界ごと特有の表現への対応などの努力によって、精度を上げていくはずである。 （※）
- b. （※） 前後の文脈を加えた解析や、業界ごと特有の表現への対応などの改善によって、精度を上げていくはずである。 （※）
- 前後の文脈を加えた解析や、業界ごと特有の表現への対応などの努力や改善によって、精度が上っていくはずである。
- 前後の文脈を加えた解析や、業界ごと特有の表現への対応などによって、精度が上っていくはずである。

I'm a bit uncomfortable with (a and b) 　　（※）  ... 精度を上げていくはずである。 （※）

It feels like an awkward version of [This car drives well.]

The following (which includes the が) would be grammatical :

> 前後の文脈を加えた解析や、業界ごと特有の表現への対応などが、精度を上げていくはずである。

---

To answer this question, you only need the text that you posted first (the part after しかし、).

3 and 4 are wrong answers because without the  が, it wouldn't be grammatical.

1 and 2 would be grammatical, but 1 is a wrong answer because the meaning would be wrong (because there is room for improvement).

Comment: Is this an assumption if はずである is correct?

Comment: @DevinaMuljono I don't think so. The answer explains why はずである is wrong in this specific context, where A社 is the subject of this sentence.

Comment: I got it i think the sentence before and after~はずである should correspond to each other(?) Like 上がって行く はずである because of 努力/改善によって(？) はず express strong feeling of supposed to or must(?)