# What is という after a verb?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does という stand for in this sentence:

春から介護の専門学校に通う**という**女子生徒は「列車に乗るのは久しぶりですが、最後にみんなで乗ることができ、いい思い出になりました」と話していました。

Is it modifying 専門学校 meaning 'the so called...' or is it a different grammatical stucture?

Comment: Maybe this? http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/define

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 春から介護の専門学校に通うという女子生徒は「列車に乗るのは久しぶりですが、最後にみんなで乗ることができ、いい思い出になりました」と話していました。

と is a quotative particle, and いう is "to say" (言う). So it literally means "saying that", but as a set phrase, という has various idiomatic usages (including "called" as in "a tablet *called* iPad"). In this case, it is used to indicate hearsay.

- [what is the difference between である ＆ という](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33563/5010)

It implies that 春から介護の専門学校に通う is not a confirmed fact from the author's point of view. It's just a piece of information the writer heard from the student herself.